# split a dataset into N pieces

Tags: sas

N is determined by the number of distinct values in particular fields. In actual scenario, N is quite large since each field (char column) has many distinct values.

**Sample Data:**

```
A  B  C  D  V1 V2 V3 V4
ab ba cf dm
ab bc cf dm
ab bc cg dm
ac bd cg dm
```

`Vi's` are numerical columns (missing values may exist). A B C D are characters with values indicating different subgroups (no missing data).

The number of character columns is unknown. The number of distinct values in each character column is also unknown.

If col(i) has n(i) distinct values, then `N = n(1) * n(2) * ...`. In the sample data, `N = 2 * 3 * 2 * 1`.

**Target:**

To produce one data set for each unique combination of different fields.

**Relevant links:**

[Split SAS dataset StackoverfLow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14955465/split-sas-dataset)

http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/Split_Data_into_Subsets

Comment: As noted in sascommunity link this isn't recommended. Why do you want to split the data set out to smaller subsets? And what do you want your output to be? And what's your question here, since you seem to have solutions but claim they're too slow but a hash solution will be difficult for you to debug or extend?

Comment: So you want just to produce one dataset for each unique combination of character vars c(1)-c(i)?

Comment: What are you trying to do with separate datasets that you can't do with by-group processing?

Comment: Keeping it in one dataset, with some sort of 'by' variable, is significantly superior to splitting it in nearly all cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, hash tables **really would** be better (and probably easier to manage). Still, how about this?

Test data:

```
data dummy ;
input  A $ B $ C $ D $ v1 v2 v3 v4 ;
cards ;
ab ba cf dm 1 2 3 4 
ab bc cf dm 5 6 7 8
ab bc cf dm 1 2 3 4
ab bc cg dm 9 0 1 2
ac bd cg dm 3 4 5 6
;run ;
```

Sort data by character variables (just need to list them here though):

```
proc sort data=dummy ;
  by a b c d ;
data output ;
  set dummy end=EndoFile ;
  by a b c d ;
  if first.d then count+1 ;
  if EndoFile then call symput('ucount',count) ;
run ;
```

Create separate datasets from the original data ;

```
%macro split ;
%do i=1 %to &ucount ;
data d&i ;
  set output(where=(count=&i)) ;
run ;
%end ;
%mend split ;
%split ;
```

Comment: Hash tables are better largely because they allow you to generate a custom dataset on the fly without knowing how many you have.

Answer (score 1):

Using the same dummy dataset as Bendy created, this will split up into one dataset per unique combination of a, b, c and d:

```
data dummy ;
input  A $ B $ C $ D $ v1 v2 v3 v4 ;
cards ;
ab ba cf dm 1 2 3 4 
ab bc cf dm 5 6 7 8
ab bc cf dm 1 2 3 4
ab bc cg dm 9 0 1 2
ac bd cg dm 3 4 5 6
;run ;

%macro lup;
proc sql noprint;
  select distinct compress(a!!"_"!!b!!"_"!!c!!"_"!!d) into :dataset1-:dataset99999
  from dummy;
quit;
%put &sqlobs;
data
  %do i=1 %to &sqlobs;
    &&dataset&i
  %end;
  ;
  set dummy;
  %do i=1 %to &sqlobs;
    if compress(a!!"_"!!b!!"_"!!c!!"_"!!d)="&&dataset&i" then output &&dataset&i;
  %end;
run;
%mend;
%lup;
```