# sas subset data by group

Tags: sas, sas-macro

This might be a stupid question, but I'm having a hard time with this issue.
I have data something like

```
animal firstcharacter
mouse  m
dog    d
cat    c
monkey m
donkey d
```

I want to divide this "original" data into several datasets based on firstcharacter.

In this example, I should have 3 groups (c, d, m).

This is easy if I do this one by one:

```
data new_c; set original; if firstcharacter = "c" then; run;
data new_d; set original; if firstcharacter = "d" then; run;
data new_m; set original; if firstcharacter = "m" then; run;
```

The problem is, I have hundreds of these groups in the actual data.
Is there a simple way (using either do loop or macro variable) to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: There are other roughly similar questions; I don't close-as-duplicate only because none of them really have ideal answers.  Search for "Split SAS dataset" to see several, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14955465/split-sas-dataset).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty easy to do with hash tables.  This is the 'easy' version, which requires a sort but doesn't require a hash of hashes or any real management.

```
data have;
input animal $ firstcharacter $;
datalines;
mouse  m
dog    d
cat    c
monkey m
donkey d
;;;;
run;

proc sort data=have;  
  by firstcharacter;
run;

data _null_;
  set have;
  by firstcharacter;
  if _n_=1 then do;
    declare hash h;
  end;

  if first.firstcharacter then do;
    h = _new_ hash();
    h.defineKey('animal');
    h.defineData('animal','firstcharacter');
    h.defineDone();
  end;

  rc = h.add();

  if last.firstcharacter then do;
    rc = h.output(dataset:cats('new_',firstcharacter));
  end;
run;
```

More complex methods exist using a hash of hashes (search on that if you want to know more).

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't know about 'hash' stuff, but your logic makes sense!

Comment: You can read about it, of course. You can also read the link I posted to see other ways (macros).  This is the most _efficient_.